# Electron Diffraction Pattern (spot in the center)

Tags: electrons, diffraction, crystals

So in the diffraction pattern of an electron beam (or an electron) in a polycrystaline material we observe rings and a central spot . What's exactly the central spot?
Is it not diffracted electrons due to the experimental machine errors ? Is it just the front of thé wave ? Is it just some rings really close together?
Thanks.

Comment: It's primarily the non-scattered part of the beam.

Comment: In a TEM there is often the option of blocking the direct beam to get better diffraction patterns (not blowing out pixels on the camera with the direct beam intensity).